# Manejo de subreporte en Ireport

Tags: java, ireport

Como se realiza el paso de parámetros desde un reporte a un subreporte en Ireport...

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: CUál reporte (el jrxml)? Cuál subreport? Cómo lo ejecutas? Cuál clase datasource? Cómo la ejecutas? No pongas a adivinar a las personas que te leen, ponte en nuestro lugar. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: _No ignores los comentarios_. Estás destruyendo aún más tu pregunta. Lee [ask].

Comment: Haz click en el subreporte y en la ventana de propiedades casi al final de *Subreport properties* esta la propiedad *Parameters*, presiona el botón con tres puntos (`…`).

Comment: Ok gracias!!!...y si deseo poner los campos del datasource que estoy utilizando como puedo hacer?....yo estoy pasando parametros y un datasource como fuente de datos al reporte principal....ahora deseo que ese datasource se imprima en el subreporte